# How do I implement toString() in a class that is mapped with Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading, tostring

I have an instance of a class that I got from a Hibernate session. That session is long gone. Now, I'm calling `toString()` and I'm getting the expected `LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session` since I'm trying to access a reference which Hibernate didn't resolve during loading of the instance (lazy loading).

I don't really want to make the loading eager since it would change the query from about 120 characters to over 4KB (with eight joins). And I don't have to: All I want to display in `toString()` is the ID of the referenced object; i.e. something that Hibernate needs to know at this point in time (or it couldn't do the lazy loading).

So my question: How do you handle this case? Never try to use references in `toString()`? Or do you call `toString()` in the loading code just in case? Or is there some utility function in Hibernate which will return something useful when I pass it a reference which *might* be lazy? Or do you avoid references in `toString()` altogether?

Comment: If Java had closure you could do: String x = lazyToString({ => this.getY() }) + lazyToString({ => this.getZ() }); and catch the expection in the lazyToString method. The overhead with inner classes (or try/catch) is too high to do this.

Comment: Yeah, but that wouldn't give me a session, either.

Comment: That's right. You can than only print that the value is not loaded. I thought that was the intent. You won't be able to start a session and associate the object on the toString method call.

Comment: My point is that this information must be available somewhere (see my answer below) :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to do this by setting the accesstype of the ID field to "property". like:

```
@Entity
public class Foo {
    // the id field is set to be property accessed
    @Id @GeneratedValue @AccessType("property")
    private long id;
    // other fields can use the field access type
    @Column private String stuff;
    public long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(long id) { this.id = id; }
    String getStuff() { return stuff; }
    // NOTE: we don't need a setStuff method
}
```

It's explained [here](http://256stuff.com/gray/docs/misc/hibernate_lazy_field_access_annotations.shtml).
This way the id field is allways populated when a proxy is created.

Comment: +1 I like it; there is just a minor catch: I'm using DSL syntax, so my getter is called "id()", not "getId()". I guess I could add a second getter for this special case but maybe it's possible to tell Hibernate the name of the getter?

Comment: Well, it's possible by creating your own implementation of org.hibernate.property.PropertyAccessor, and declare the fully qualified name as the value for @AccessType. On the other hand, you could create the setter (you'll need that too) and getter and make them private, so you won't see them from the rest of your app.

Comment: @EJB :Did it really work?
I have a situation where class A -----> (has a one to many rel) with class B. Both A and B have multiple properties. So when I do a toString() method call for class A it fails with LazyInitialization exception (same as above) despite setting the @AccessType("property") for the Id field of class A.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround:

```
public static String getId (DBObject dbo)
{
    if (dbo == null)
        return "null";

    if (dbo instanceof HibernateProxy)
    {
        HibernateProxy proxy = (HibernateProxy)dbo;
        LazyInitializer li = proxy.getHibernateLazyInitializer();
        return li.getIdentifier ().toString ();
    }

    try
    {
        return Long.toString (dbo.id ());
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e)
    {
        return "???";
    }
}
```

So what this code does is it fetches the ID (a 64bit number) from the object. `DBObject` is an interface which defines `long id()`. If the object is a Hibernate proxy, then I talk to its `LazyInitializer` to get the ID. Otherwise, I call `id()`. Usage:

```
class Parent {
    DBObject child;
    public String toString () {
        return "Parent (id=..., child=" + getId(child)+")");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the way that best fits good practice is a modification of the solution found on this blog: http://www.nonfunc.com/2016/02/05/jpa-performance-gotcha-tostring-really/. It needed modification for nullable fields and for Collections objects.

```
public toString() {
  return String.format("FuBar [id=%d" +  
      + ", fu=%s" // fu is a lazy non-nullable field
      + ", bar=%s" // bar is a nullable lazy field
      + ", borks=%s]", // borks is a lazy collection of Bork objects
      id,
      fu instanceof HibernateProxy ? "[null]" : fu.toString(),
      bar == null || bar instanceof HibernateProxy ? "[null]" : bar.toString(),
      borks instanceof PersistentSet ? "[null]" : borks.toString());
}
```

Comment: I see what you're doing there. Some comments: Mixing `String.format()` and `+` is bad for performance. You should also replace `[null]` with `<lazy>` because the proxy isn't null - it's just not loaded. An even better approach would be to return `<lazy TYPE ID>` where `TYPE` is the entity type and `ID` is the primary key.

Comment: Edited code for performance. The example wasn't exactly what I have and the concatenation of a variable and string does effect performance (the format string should be compiled into a static string), but I'd think that sweating over a toString's performance isn't super important, since it would be used for debugging or error reporting and shouldn't be called super frequently in production situations. I like the suggestion of specifying lazy vs null, though.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to return is the ID of the object, I imagine calling getID(), then parse the int/long as a String value at the moment you want it displayed would work just fine.  At least that's how it seems based on the question.

***EDIT***

[How to solve the LazyInitializationException using JPA and Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578433/how-to-solve-lazy-initialization-exception-using-jpa-and-hibernate-as-provider)

After viewing the comment and doing some searching I believe this may be most beneficial to your scenario.

Comment: That will throw the LazyInitializationException because the reference hasn't been resolved, yet.

Comment: Aaron, after reading this comment I edited my post.  Please see the new information and let me know if this resolves the issue.

Comment: @Woot - The answers won't help. The lazy initialized values will never be read. The tx is committed. The connection closed.

Comment: Yes I see that the transaction is already committed.  However, in the post it is a possibility to refactor the existing code to use the OpenSessionInView pattern found here: http://www.hibernate.org/43.html

If that is not doable in Aaron's environment than so be it.

Comment: @Woot: I have to agree with Thomas.

Comment: At the time I call toString(), I have no session and I don't want to create one. The question is really: How can I make toString() work inside and outside of a session?