# Overcoming lazy loading issues in Hibernate, many-to-many, relationship

Tags: java, hibernate

Teaching myself Hibernate, I have the following table structure/relationship

[image: Relationship]

Which is represented by the following classes...

#### Users

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements IUser<Role>, Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_key_seq")
    @Column(name = "key", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long key;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name = "userroles",
                    joinColumns = {
                        @JoinColumn(name = "userkey")},
                    inverseJoinColumns = {
                        @JoinColumn(name = "rolekey")})
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>(5);

    @Override
    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    // Other setters and getters

}
```

#### Roles

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role implements IRole, Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "roles_key_seq")
    @Column(name = "key", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long key;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name="parentroles",
                    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="childkey")},
                    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="parentkey")})
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>(5);

    // Other setters and getters

}
```

The problem I'm getting is this...

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: org.kaizen.chishiki.core.data.User.roles, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:575)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:554)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:180)
    at og.kaizen.chishiki.core.testdatacore.Main.<init>(Main.java:37)
    at og.kaizen.chishiki.core.testdatacore.Main.main(Main.java:25)
```

Now, I know I could set the `fetch` type to `FetchType.EAGER`, but I'd prefer not to do that, apart from performance concerns, I'm trying to learn my way around these problems ;)

I was wondering if there was a way to write a Hibernate query to satisfy this relationship and load the rows manually (it would also allow me to return the interface of `Role` instead of the implementation as I'm having to do now (would allow me to maintain that contract)).

From what I've read, it would seem that I would need to construct an `Entity` for `UserRoles`.  Not that I'm against this solution, but I was curious if there was a way to get around it.

`roles` appears in a number of other relationships, so there is no way it can form a direct relationship with the parent table (that is, I can't put the `key` of the parent table in the `role` table directly, besides, `users` can have multiple `roles`)

The other solution I had in mind was to write a stored procedure to do it for me.  While this is viable solution that I'm not above doing, it does make migrating the application to another database more difficult, not a show stopper, but I'm trying to keep these ideas in mind.

Comment: possible duplicate of [hibernate: LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/345705/hibernate-lazyinitializationexception-could-not-initialize-proxy)

Comment: I'm not sure if you can retrieve it as an instance of the interface rather than a class.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza What I want to do is return a `Set` of the interface, containing the implementations, the reason I'm trying to do this, is I have a interface layer above this that my program talks to, so that the actual mechanisms by which the data is loaded is hidden from the program layer, so if I wanted to change the "data layer" I could, that's all ;)

Comment: @Zeus Yes, I've read that, as I stated, I know I can change the `fetch` type, but I'd prefer not to do that if I can help it and I would like to know alternative solutions to this particular problem. This is just a simple example, I have more complex relationships which might end up loading 100's if not more child records ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to load users with their roles, but still keep the association lazy, use a HQL query containing a `left join fetch`:

```
select u from User u left join fetch u.roles where ...
```

If you have a User and want to make sure its roles collection is initialized before closing the session, call `Hibernate.initialize(user.getRoles())`.

Comment: How do I define the constraint/relationship between the roles and the users or doesn't it matter or is defined already by the annotations?

Comment: The association you have defined is OK. You may define an inverse association (i.e role.users), but I guess it won't really be useful. It's not to execute the above query at least.

Comment: Okay, how would you accomplish this after the `Session` has been closed?

Comment: You can't. That's how lazy fetching works: it needs a session open to be able to execute the SQL query needed to populate the association. If the roles must be fetched when fetching a user, then the transaction used to fetch the user must also fetch the roles.

Comment: Okay, this has given me some ideas and I've been able to hobble something together for the mean time. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Hibernate 4.1.6+ then one can handle those lazy association problems by using hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans property in hibernate.properties.

For More refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11913404/286588

Comment: Using this doesn't really solve the problem and can potentially cause more problems later on as this can lead to Hibernate loading a huge amount of data for one simple item. And this is why lazy loading exists.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by annotating the method in the controller as transactional.As lazy-load basically returns a list of future objects ,the method needs to be transactional.